# Validación de Slot Type en Amazon lex (Amazon connect)

Tags: aws, amazon

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña prueba en Amazon lex con un slot type personalizado.
El ejemplo que desarrollo es una tienda de flores/chocolates:
Tengo 2. **intents** con sus *utterances*:

**Tipo_flor** *Comprar flores*

**Tipo_chocolate** *Comprar chocolate*

De flores solo se admite rosas o tulipanes de calor. 
De chocolates solo se admite negro o almendrado.

1. Para cada íntent creé un Slot type específico. Centrandonos en las flores, tengo que sólo se vende rosas y tulipanes, por lo que tengo un Slot type (nombre_flor) con los values de Rosas  Tulipanes. *Mi consulta es: como puedo validar que el usuario No introduzca un valor diferente a esos dos, por ejemplo, que no ponga Margaritas.* He leído que con una función Lambda, pero ¿hay otro modo?, ya que no tengo mucha práctica en programación de lambda.
2. Otra cosa, este Amazon lex esta enlazado con Amazon connect, de manera que según el intent que elija el usuario se va por un camino o por otro según el utterances ("comprar flores","comprar chocolates"), esto funciona bien cuando hago la prueba con voz, pero me falla cuando intento llegar al Slot type y sospecho que es porque no está validado desde el Lex *¿hay manera de validarlo en el connect?.*

Perdón por la extensión, y Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final usé una función Lambda para realizar las validaciones.  Creo que es la manera de hacerlo.

Saludos,

Jose Maria

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu responder sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!